# Index Bound Error

Tags: c#

When form load I want that all the ID from Student Table insert in another Table. 
But when I run the program ID only 1 ID insert in table but when 2 ID is going to be
insert it gives error of:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

So anybody can help me

```
List<string> files = new List<string>();

query =  " select student_no from student_registration";

cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

con.Open();

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
   files.Add(dr[0].ToString());
}

con.Close();

for (int i = 1; i <= files.Count; i++)
{
    query = "insert into student_fees values(" + files[i] + ",'0','0')";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: You don't have to shout !

Comment: Let the two other fields of `student_fees` have a default value of `0` and then just execute `"INSERT INTO student_fees (TheFieldName) SELECT student_no FROM student_registration"` - "TheFieldName" should of course be the field name of the field in the `student_fees` table, you want to put the `student_no` values in.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= files.Count; i++)
```

must be

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
```

Improving on it, you could use a foreach-loop:

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    query = "insert into student_fees values(" + file + ",'0','0')";
```

And while we are at it, research parameter binding for your statements. Imagine the statement if in your list, one element is

```
"X,'0','0'); DROP DATABASE; --"
```

Comment: Thnk You Very Much foreach loop is working